# Definition of 'xxx' must be imported from module 'yyy' before it is required

Tags: objective-c, module, clang

For example, We have a pod 'Dependency3' declared Class A

```
@interface A : NSObject

- (void)test;

@end
```

pod 'Dependency1' declared Class B and a category of Class A

```
@interface B : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *bText;

@end

@interface A (Dep1)

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aTextDep1;

@end
```

pod 'Dependency2' declared categories of Class A and B

```
@interface A (Dep2)

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aTextDep2;

@end

@interface B (Dep2)

- (NSString *)bTextDep2;

@end
```

And the dependency relations are no problem:

```
Dependency2 -> Dependency3 & Dependency1
Dependency1 -> Denpendency3
```

In podfile, we enable some of them's modular_headers

```
  pod 'Dependency1', :path => './Dependency1', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Dependency2', :path => './Dependency2', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Dependency3', :path => './Dependency3'
```

Now if you use class A and B in main project or in another new pod, compiler will tell you

```
Definition of 'A' must be imported from module 'Dependency1.A_Dep1' before it is required
```

This problem will sometimes disappeared after I cleaning build folder and module cache folder.

This simple example is simplified from my case which is found in a large component-based project with objc and swift code.

The most important things is why it happened, maybe the include order of module maps or others? I'd be appreciated if someone can help me.

Comment: how do you import class A in the Dependency1 module header? do you have to have Dependency2 to reproduce this? could you try to repro the same issue without cocoapods by declaring 3 framework targets in a blank project? (and share this)